# Save text pdf direct to s3 without having to save it locally

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, itext

I am generating pdf files using itext 5 and Java, and saving them locally then saving these local saved files on AWS S3. Is there a way to just send them straight to S3 without having to save them locally. I have seen a few examples but none is working for me.

This is how am generating the pdf file

```
 String path = //local directory on my computer
 Document document = new Document();
 PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(path));
 document.open();
 
 // add text to document
 document.close();
```

This is how I save it on s3

```
public void saveFileToS3(String pathLocal, String pathAws) {
   
    // init aws 

    PutObjectRequest objectRequest = PutObjectRequest.builder()
        .bucket(bucketName)
        .key(folderName + "/" + pathAws)
        .build();
    
    CompletableFuture<PutObjectResponse> future = s3Client.putObject(objectRequest,
        AsyncRequestBody.fromFile(Paths.get(pathLocal))
    );
    
    future.whenComplete((resp, err) -> {
      try {
        if (resp != null) {
          System.out.println("Object uploaded. Details: " + resp);
        } else {
          err.printStackTrace();
        }
      } finally {
        s3Client.close();
      }
    });
    
    future.join();
  }
```

***String pathLocal*** is the path where am saving the file locally, while ***String pathAws*** is the path on S3 where the file is saved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I found out a way, I converted the itext file to a byte array and uploaded the pdf file as a byte array

```
Document document = new Document();
 ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  
 PdfWriter.getInstance(document, byteArrayOutputStream);

 document.open();

//add stuff to pdf

 document.close();

//convert it into a byte array
byte[] pdfBytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()
```

When uploading it to S3 I passed the bytes instead of the file path as I was doing before

```
CompletableFuture<PutObjectResponse> future = s3Client.putObject(objectRequest,
        AsyncRequestBody.fromBytes(pdfBytes)
    );
```

Comment: Note that this is going all sorts of wrong if the generated PDF is large.

Answer (score 1):

First a sidenote:

> `new FileOutputStream(path)`

Your code is buggy; you *cannot* make new resources (as in, streams/readers/writers that represent an actual resource: Be it a socket on a network, a file on a disk, that sort of thing), without guarding it via try-with-resources.

More generally though, you don't want a FOS here. You want to have a stream such that any bytes produced by the pdf gen code and sent off via `thatOutputStream.write` are put directly on the network.

This is sort of possible, but not easy in this particular case.

Let me first try to explain the concerns that these libraries have so that you fully understand why this is not quite easy, and that you can therefore judge the various solutions around for suitability to your particular project.

At the heart of your problem is that you have 2 separate processes that each are dependent on another.

- The PDF gen code wants to generate PDF bytes, and wants complete freedom: If it needs to query a database as part of the job, it wants to be able to do that. However, it is limited by the output channel: It could in theory be generating many GBs a second: It wants to eventually stop itself (*block* its thread, or, relinquish control to whatever is processing its output so it can process a bunch of it) if the output channel is 'full'. For example, if your disk can store at 1GB/s and your PDF code is generating an infinite size PDF and can do so at 2GB/s, the PDF code needs to slow down.
- The output channel code, in this case, the AWS S3 putObject code, wants the freedom to block as well: If the network buffers are full, it has to wait: There is a limit to how fast it can push packets out the back of the computer, after all. It is also limited by the input: If the PDF gen code generates at 1GB/s, but the AWS S3 putObject code can send at 2GB/s, then the putObject code has to slow itself down; it can't send more bytes if there aren't any bytes to send.

**Usually** in java code, the model is very simple: One side (producer, or consumer) is considered controlling, and not the bottleneck. For example, if you have code that generates infinite zeroes and writes it out to disk:

```
byte[] allZeroes = new byte[60000];
try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("test.dat")) {
    while (true) fos.write(allZeroes);
}
```

Very simple code. However, note that the 'producer' side, which is controlling here, is in fact handicapped. The `write` method *blocks* - if the disk is busy processing, that `write` method will not immediately return. Whilst the disk is busily processing it all, **the CPU is idle**. It could have been spending time making more zeroes!

In this example that's silly - the CPU can produce zeroes incredibly quickly, the 'producing' code is many orders of magnitude faster than the 'consuming' code, and it makes sense for the production side to just chill out for a bit as the consumer is busy processing it all.

But imagine code that worked a little differently: Instead of writing an endless stream of zeroes, imagine code that is mining bitcoin, and writing the mining blocks (worth thousands of dollars each, which should indicate how slowly they'd be generated. One a month is already very impressive). Clearly the handicap is in this sense idiotic: The CPU should be busy mining bitcoin, not twiddling its thumbs waiting for the disk. This is case where you want both processes (or at the very least, the slower process, in this example the producer) to never just wait for the other side. The bottleneck should not be made to wait around.

The code that is busy generating PDF data was halfway through a for loop when it wants to send data out to the putObject code, but the putObject code was halfway through calculating a hash over a segment of data when it wanted more PDF data. If neither side is supposed to twiddle its thumbs while the other is busy, then there is no way out except having 2 fibers (stacktraces, effectively), and having these fibers pass data to each other. In java, this **must** be done with threads - [Project Loom](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/loom/) is on the horizon and would give you interesting single-core options, but Project Loom is not part of java quite yet.

The putObject code is specifically designed around this idea; normally, an output works by returning an `OutputStream`; `Files.newOutputStream` returns one, so does `new FileOutputStream()`, so does `socket.getOutputStream`, as does `servletHttpResponse.getOutputStream()`. But not AWS putObject: It doesn't return anything; it **wants** an InputStream. Similarly, the PDF code doesn't return anything either, it **wants** an OutputStream.

And thus, the dilemma.

The threaded solution is pretty simple, though. You need one thread to generate the PDF, and one thread to send it to AWS. You link the two with a [piped stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/PipedInputStream.html).

An alternative solution is to go back to the model that one side will just wait around and twiddle its thumbs for a while, but the AWS API doesn't support it. Here is a [gist that tries to give it to you by using the multipart feature](https://gist.github.com/blagerweij/ad1dbb7ee2fff8bcffd372815ad310eb).